# What's wrong with bottle.py template paths?

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to add internationalization to my page. Let's say, the route is /RU/index

```
@route('/<path>/<page:re:.*>')
def callback(path, page):
    fullpath = ('/%s/%s.html' % (path, page))
    print('fullpath %s' % fullpath)
    return template(fullpath)
```

Why doesn't it return template from file in /views/RU/index.html?

Comment: You are going to have `.html` twice.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry, I've msspelled. Of course, the route is /RU/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add path to TEMPLATE_PATH

```
def bottle_monkeypatch():
    """
    This adds /common folder to bottle template path, thus
    makes templating cleaner and more manageable.
    """
    from bottle import TEMPLATE_PATH
    global TEMPLATE_PATH
    TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, './views/common')
```